# array of variable size in C. Is it ok?

Tags: c, arrays, file, file-io

My motto is to write some dummy data into the file with minimal load on the system. The size of the data is not known and specified at run time.

For this I can think of 2 solutions.

1) Using Dynamic memory allocation

```
reserve_size_in_file (int reserve_size, FILE *fp) 
{
    char *p
    p = malloc(reserve_size)
    fwrite(p, sizeof(*p), 1, fp);
    free(p);
}
```

2) Using arrays

```
reserve_size_in_file (int reserve_size, FILE *fp) 
{
    char arr[reserve_size];
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(arr), 1, fp);
}
```

I thought the second method will not work as declaring an array with variable length(ewww...), i thought is not allowed. But it is working. Now my question is, is it ok to use it like this? Also, if there is another better way to do this pls suggest.

**Note: I cannot use `fallocate()` because I have to deal only with stream IO.**

**Edit:**

I just saw that i can use fileno(fp) and use fallocate(). But i donot see many applications using fallocate(). Are there any concerns in using fallocate()

Ex: `fallocate(fileno(fp), 0, 0, 100000);`

Comment: In option 1, you are leaking memory. You need to `free()` the memory you've allocated with `malloc()`.

Comment: Does it really have to consume the amount of storage or would be a sparse file acceptable as well?

Comment: Sorry @datenwolf I dint quite get the question you asking. Sory for my poor english. In mine the user can reserve any amount of data. I should be prepared for it to be till 20 MB.

Comment: @Manty: On most operating systems files can be "sparse", i.e. a file's length is not the same as the amount of bytes actually stored in it. There may be holes in it, which when you read them come out as NUL bytes, but which are not actually stored on the storage device. Reserving storage for a file makes sense if you expect it to be filled later with actual data and don't want to wait for the OS to actually allocate the bytes on the storage device. –– If you don't need actual storage to be preallocated you could just use `fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, offset);` to go anywhere in the stream to write data

Comment: @Manty: So say your program demands for something to be written at offset 15MiB from the start of the file, then you just `fseek` there and write the data. All the portions you don't actually touch still account for the total addressable file length, but will not consume storage on disk. Also see my answer on how to reserve storage without going through the length of dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @datenwolf That is interesting. What would be the size of the file in that case? So when i extract information from file, what will i see in this void space suppose i did not write any information into this space?

Comment: The question evolved a bit and @datenwolf answer gets to the core of your evolved question.

Comment: @Manty: Like I already wrote, when reading from the holes you get back NUL bytes. The size as reported by `ls` would be the offset of the last byte in the file + 1. To see the actual number of allocated blocks you must use the `stat` command on the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
reserve_size_in_file (int reserve_size, FILE *fp) 
{
    /* Usual HDDs have a block size of 512, but big
     * block storage is becoming popular. */
    char arr[4096]; 

    /* initialize to 0xff, since runs of NUL bytes might
     * be transparently replaced with sparse file holes. */
    memset(arr, 0xff, sizeof(arr));

    while(reserve_size > sizeof(arr)) {
        fwrite(arr, sizeof(arr), 1, fp);
        reserve_size -= sizeof(arr);
    }
    fwrite(arr, reserve_size, 1, fp);
}
```

This completely avoids the dynamic memory allocation and operates in nice to work with block sizes.

Comment: +1 With the evolved question this answer is probably the better one.

Comment: Thank you. I wish to accept this answer. But could you please comment on fallocate() part aswell?

Comment: @Manty: `fallocate`, or if you want to stay portable `posix_fallocate` will essentially do the same as my code snippet, but "behind the scenes" and without an auxiliary buffer. Most applications do not use fallocate, butcause it's no use to them. In fact there are only very few situations in which one actually wants to preallocate space on a storage device. In fact for me only two come to mind readily: *Live video recording* and *database storage clusters*, and even databases make only little use of preallocation. So here's the question: Why exactly do you think that preallocation is required?

Comment: Basically i am creating a library that will help the user to create a ELF type object based on different data(logs, or other information). So if user wants to allocate some space in the object and come back to it later and write some data, i want to give support. That is the whole idea. Hope i am clear.

Comment: @Manty: Then you don't need preallocation. Sparse files is what you want. Just `fseek` to the offset in the file where things should go and write. No need to brush over the gaps in between. I take it those ELFs are to be linked into an executable. Don't worry, those holes mean no harm. Executables are memory mapped by the kernel into the process memory space and all pages that come to lie on holes read zero; if the file was mmaped for writing, writing into a hole transparently fills the gap in storage.

Comment: Thanks @datenwolf. I will be using it. I am now trying to find some official place to convince my co members. Unfortunately man page doesn't talk much about this. Thank you again for apt solutions.

Comment: @Manty: Have a look at the man page of `lseek` which is the underlying syscall being used by `fseek`. It states: `If data is later written at this point, subsequent reads of the data
       in the gap (a "hole") return null bytes ('\0') until data is actually written into the gap.`

Comment: I prefer `while(reserve_size) {
    int n = reserve_size;
    if (n > sizeof arr) n = sizeof arr;
    fwrite(arr, n, 1, fp);
    reserve_size -= n;
}` ... it would also be a good idea to check whether fwrite failed, but hardly anyone does.

Answer (score 3):

[Variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)(*VLA*) are a C99 standard feature and are ok to use as long as you know all the compilers you will use support C99. the C11 standard though made variable length arrays optional. Both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) support VLAs even outside of C99 mode as an extension. `Visual Studio` on the other hand did not support C99 until recently and I don't think they support VLA yet.

The alternative if you don't know the size ahead of time is dynamic memory allocation via malloc.

As Jens points out, VLAs do go on the stack and you have [limited stack space](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt) which can be a problem if the size of your arrays is large, if that is the case then you will have to use dynamic memory.

Comment: I just edited my ques. Could you pls explain on that aswell. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

VLA have two disadvantages

- you don't know how much data you can reserve "on the stack" for them
- there is no error return if the allocation doesn't succeed.

So unless you know for sure that your array will never go beyond some kilo of data, I'd not chose them for this purpose. Otherwise if the allocation fails you'd have spurious errors due to stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. Any other option that i have other than the above 2? One more i can think of is to write 1 byte in a for loop everytime fseeking to start. Wht is the standard way generally?

Comment: There is not really a standard for that. What many people do would be to reserve an array of fixed size, say 8k, and iterate over that.

Comment: I just edited my ques. Could you pls explain on that aswell. Thank you.